# SDL_LoadBMP into glTexImage2D results in scewed colors

Tags: opengl, shaders, textures, color, sdl2

I read up on this but i can not find the error.
Some suggest switching the format from RBA to RGBA but the surface data says it is 3 byte data.

Here are snippets and results of my source.

Loading the Image:

```
std::string bmpname = filename + ".bmp";

SDL_Surface * surface = SDL_LoadBMP(bmpname.c_str());
if (surface)
{
    glGenTextures(1, &m_texture_name);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture_name);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    GLenum mode;

    switch (surface->format->BytesPerPixel)
    {
    case 3: mode = GL_RGB; break;
    case 4: mode = GL_RGBA; break;
    default:
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "" << *this << " failed recognize byteformat '" << bmpname << "'.";
        break;
    }


    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, surface->w, surface->h, 0, mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels);
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
}
else
{
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "" << *this << " failed to load '" << bmpname << "'.";
}
```

Output on the left, texture on the right:
[image]

Shaders:

```
//Vertex Shader
#version 120
attribute vec3 position_ATTRIB;
attribute vec2 texcoords_ATTRIB;
varying vec2 texcoords;
void main()
{
    texcoords = texcoords_ATTRIB;
    gl_Position = vec4(position_ATTRIB, 1.0);
}

//Fragment Shader
#version 120
uniform sampler2D diffuse;
varying vec2 texcoords;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(diffuse, texcoords);
}
```

What is going on here, why is the color palette blueish?

Comment: The yellow/cyan swap makes me think your BMP may be in GL_BGR(A) instead of GL_RGB(A).

Comment: Yes, i tested it and that is what was causing it. I there a way to auto detect it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking how many bytes there are per pixel, but you are not checking how colours are ordered, and it could be RGBA or BGRA (or possibly something else). You need something like this instead of `mode = GL_RGBA` (little-endian machines):

```
if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
    mode = GL_RGBA;
else
    mode = GL_BGRA;
```

If you want a more generic solution, create a temporary surface (`SDL_CreateRGBSurface`) with the exact image format you want, then copy `surface` onto that temporary surface (`SDL_BlitSurface`).

Comment: I see. This solves my tutorial level issues for now but i will defiitely read into the generic variant.

Answer (score 0):

For this case the BMP was not in RGB Format but in BGR Format.
Switching those made the colors appear correctly.

Im am not sure how a generic version would look like.